# Why has ArrayList add E and remove Object

Tags: java, arraylist

For ArrayList we have:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
```

but for remove we have:

```
public boolean remove(Object o) {
```

Why isn't it?:

```
public boolean remove(E e) {
```

Comment: ArrayList Remove method call o.equals(elementData[index]) and Object equals returns (this == obj), which actually check references equality, if we pass E in the remove method o.equals will be specific to Generic E.